# How to overcome the dilemma caused by delay in receiving offer letter?

Tags: negotiation, job-offer

I was recently interviewed by a giant software consulting firm. There were around 8 rounds of interview over phone and face-to-face spanned over 45 days. I attended the last round termed as salary negotiation discussion with HR 2 weeks ago and HR confirmed me that the offer letter will be released within a week. Since then there has been no response from the company's side neither did I follow up with the HR. Should I call the HR to inquire about current status of my application? I ask this because I'm being asked to refrain from doing that by my seniors. The reason put forth was that a slightest urgency shown from my side would be considered as my desperation to get a job, hence will adversely affect the offered salary. Next, since it is a big MNC so processing and approvals before issuing an offer letter takes time, so I should wait. Please guide.

Comment: Let me explain: we can't give you advice about life at large. We also don't answer questions that are higly localized to your situation because they will not be useful for others viewing the site and we can't possibly know all the details. So should you or shouldn't you do something that is highly specific to your company and situation? We don't know. We can't comment in good faith.

Comment: Delays in receiving offer letters are localized? You want me to believe that every other organization barring this one issues offer letters on time? How can this question be specific or localized. If it is then there are scores of open questions floating around here are localized too.

Comment: @NoobUnChained a word of warning this is NOT a forum. This is a question and answer site where questions specific to the workplace are asked and answered by those with the knowledge to deal with them. This is not a discussion forum

Comment: @NoobUnChained I'm not saying that you don't have a valid question in there. What I'm saying is that people are probably downvoting because it does not adhere to the format of this site well enough. That is my guess anyway. BTW the question title is totally different from what you have posted as the core of the question in your comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Should I call the HR to inquire about current status of my application?*

Yes, call.

And in the future, always leave an interview (or negotiation) with the question "What is the next step?" If the response is something like "We'll send you an offer letter" you can then ask "when".

In my mind, you are simply trying to make sure that something didn't get lost in the mail (or email), and not acting desperate. As long as you ask only once, it should be fine.

Good luck.